# Virtualized panel that arranges children uniformly

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I am trying to use a `GridView` that will arrange it's child uniformly, much like the [`UnifromGrid`](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/UniformGrid) of *Community Toolkit*, but a virtualizing one.

The reason I cannot use the default `Itemspanel` of `GridView` is that I think it determines the size of all other cells by the 1st cell, look at this:

[image]

Notice the blank spaces on the right and also, Items having bigger dimensions are being clipped with the size of the 1st Item.

I tried using the [`UniformGrid'](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/UniformGrid), but it's not virtualized and my app actually struggles sometimes and becomes very laggy when there are a lot of Items.

I also tried to extend `VirtualizingPanel` to create a custom `Panel`, but [it's not possible for now.](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/217)

Is there any thing that I can do now to solve this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the [`AdaptiveGridView` control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/adaptivegridview) from the Windows Community Toolkit? It will allow you to resize the items automatically based on the available width. However, making the items exactly square would be a challenge, as it changes the width with how the window expands.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
If you don't mind fixed sized cells, you can specifiy this on the ItemsPanel.

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel> 
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" ItemHeight="200" ItemWidth="200"/>  
        </ItemsPanelTemplate> 
    </GridView.ItemsPanel> 
</GridView>
```

**Option 2:**
In the pre-release versions of the WinUI NuGet from Microsoft there is a new list control called "Repeater", that in conjunction with its "UniformGridLayout" may do as you want.

At the current moment you can find a sample of this in the XamlControlsGallery repo here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery/blob/master/XamlControlsGallery/ControlPages/ItemsRepeaterPage.xaml

Note this is still pre-release, so there's very little documentation, and the controls surface area is likely to change (and infact, has changed a few times already). Repeater is also not a child of Selector or ListView, so you lose automatic ItemContainers, SelectionModes, ItemClicking, etc. You'll have to manually add those as you see fit - repeater is essentially a new list-presenting base class more analogous to ItemsControl rather than GridView or ListView.

This comes with caveats - the Virtualization only works natively on the 17763 SDK and upwards - on lower SDK you also need to use a ScrollAnchorProvider too enable virtualizing, as line 110 of the sample shows.

Comment: I don't want to use fixed width, 'cause,  it will be determined in runtime. Thanks

Comment: I will give it a shot